# group values by price and similar name

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
[{Name:".com.in", Price: 3},{Name:".net.in", Price:3}, {Name:".org.in", Price:5}, {Name:".com", Price:9},{Name:".net", Price:9},{Name:".in", Price:3}]
```

I want to group these values into groups with priority in order: price,similar domain extension

- {Name:".com.in", Price: 3},{Name:".net.in", Price:3}
- {Name:".org.in", Price:5}  => similar name with .com.in but different price.
- {Name:".com", Price:9}
- {Name:".net", Price:9}  => same price with .com but different name
- {Name:".in", Price:3}

I tried to loop through the values but seems not a bright idea. I open to server side c# or angularjs, underscorejs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use groupBy of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module.

Just add the JS file from here: http://www.cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-filter to your project and use following code.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['angular.filter']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    $scope.items = [
        {Name:".com.in", Price: 3},
        {Name:".net.in", Price:3}, 
        {Name:".org.in", Price:5}, 
        {Name:".com", Price:9},
        {Name:".net", Price:9},
        {Name:".in", Price:3}
    ];
}

div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in items | groupBy: 'Price'">
        <b>Price: {{ key }}</b>
      <li ng-repeat="item in value">
          item: <i> {{ item.Name }} </i>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If I totally understood you, this is what you want.

This is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7394/) with working example.

Comment: thanks but it won't work like what i want, i can use underscorejs as well but for similar name i guess i need to use Levenshtein Distance algorithm instead of comparing manually the domain extension.

Answer (score 1):

(assuming you are doing this server side due to the c# tag)...

I would suggest using a `List<T>` to store the items rather than an array.

You can then use the `List.Sort(IComparer comp)` to sort the list.

Then you can build multiple `IComparer` objects to sort your object on whatever you want (one comparer for price, another for name, another for...).

If your comparer uses both grouping and priority order logic then the result will be one long list with elements sorted by group and priority order. i.e.

```
Compare(Object x, Object y)
{
    MyItem i1 = (MyItem)x;
    MyItem i2 = (MyItem)y;

    if(i1.Price != i2.Price)
    {
        //sort by group
        return (i1.Price < i2.Price);
    }
    else
    {
        //sort priority within group
        return LevenshteinDistance(i1.Name,i2.Name);
    }
}

private int LevenshteinDistance(string s1, string s2)
{
    ...
}
```

If you need to work out the group boundaries, use another IComparer with only group logic (ie if IComparer says A < B then A and B are different groups). Use this comparer when you are sequentially processing the list.